# How to push an element to an array in a loop

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array which is contained inside a wrapper array, what I'm trying to do is to push an element inside each sub array.

```
    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
      $data[] =  [
        'email'                     => $customer['email'] ?? '',
        'firstname'                 => $customer['first_name'] ?? '',
        'lastname'                  => $customer['last_name'] ?? '',
        'phone'                     => $customer['phone'] ?? '',
        'country'                   => $customer["default_address"]["country"] ?? '',
        'city'                      => $customer["default_address"]["city"] ?? ''
      ];
    }
```

And I want to push this element if that condition is met

```
      if ($this->shop === 'shop.com') {
        $data['brand'] = 'sony';
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an element into subarray in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59875208/how-to-add-an-element-into-subarray-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does not work as expected?

Comment: @AksenP Thanks, yes this kinda answer my question... foreach lop didnt cross my mind! but i think that the below answer is better fit for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing a subarray to the `data` array immediately, just use a variable:

```
$item =  [
   'email'                     => $customer['email'] ?? '',
   'firstname'                 => $customer['first_name'] ?? '',
   'lastname'                  => $customer['last_name'] ?? '',
   'phone'                     => $customer['phone'] ?? '',
   'country'                   => $customer["default_address"]["country"] ?? '',
   'city'                      => $customer["default_address"]["city"] ?? ''
];
```

Check your condition, and set the `brand` property accordingly:

```
if ($this->shop === 'shop.com') {
   $item['brand'] = 'sony';
}
```

Finally, push the `$item` to the `data` array:

```
$data[] = $item;
```

Hope this helps.